# Beginner question - what is wrong

Tags: discussion, specific-question, new-users

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Choose multiple files without window manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58297654/choose-multiple-files-without-window-manager)

Could anyone please explain what is wrong with my question? It's unique, it's clear, it's short and it has all needed information. I would understand if I get some answers like 'go google' (googled a lot) or 'duplicate question' (checked for it) but all I get just two minuses and silence. I am not offended or frustrated nor concerned about my reputation too much, I really need an answer to do my job. It is more confusing as my previous question was answered in most beautiful way and it helped me a lot.

Comment: So why the downvotes?

Comment: There is no question in your question

Comment: it's way too broad, noone can answer that without developping a whole project for you.

Comment: @fbueckert it was below zero, that's why I ask.

Comment: I've broken the silence. Check other questions (with positive votes) you'll see the difference.

Comment: your other question has code in it. It's not too broad. It's completely on-topic because your questions are accurate and get accurate answers.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre excuse me, but the question is exact to the point for anyone who works with R language. I need just a name of a function or a package, that's it, one word.

Comment: @Eugene so.... an off-site ressource? That's off-topic :/

Comment: I've changed the close reason to ""Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it"

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre actually, my first question was way more broad and had less needed information.

Comment: adding code may prevent the question from being too broad. People see your problem more clearly.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre R is programming language, right?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I indicated two packages that do not work. It is more than anough.

Comment: If it was enough, it wouldn't be closed.  Please try to meet our standards instead of arguing that it is.

Comment: @Eugene questions shouldn't ask for off-site resources. You're literally asking for the name of the package to do what you want... that is off-topic..... no amount of editing will change that, no amount of "but this" will change that :/...

Comment: Not to mention you are just getting progressively more obstinate, so that's going to invite more downvotes itself. It SHOULDN'T, but it does.

Comment: @patricksweeney just trying to get answer to my question.

Comment: @EugeneVlasov then LISTEN to what everyone is telling you, because they are 100% correct.

Comment: @Patrice I am asking for a function in R programming language. There is 'r' tag on SO. How can it be off-site? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Eugene because not everything about the programming language is on topic. The close reason on your question even says it, and specifically what's off-topic. "asking for off site resource". It even says what to do instead... https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  says "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Just because an `r` tag exists, doesn't mean anything related to `r` can be asked. Stackoverflow itself is not a code writing service, nor is it a place where you should ask for suggestions/libraries/etc. That is what I think everyone is trying to tell you. You should post code that you have tried, indicate the error/problem, and then ask for a solution. That's the basic 'recipe' for a decent SO question.

Comment: With all respect, nobody here knows what R is, right?

Comment: Do **you** understand that asking for off-site stuff, like a package, a function, a library, is off-topic? no matter the language used.... you insinuating people don't understand instead of reading what we're telling you, is downright insulting. Almost trolling at this point. If you don't want to read what we tell you... good luck

Comment: @Patrice I may appear stubborn but I beg you to understand that **all** R language consists of packages. That's how it was made. There are **no** parts of R that are no packages. I think to downvote a question that one do not understand can be more insulting than truing to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: if you want to know how to perform multiple selection on a file selector in the file selector GUI in R, that's really a very confused way to ask.

Comment: @Eugene so you don't code, AT ALL, in R? Interesting, cause I do.... but whatever. And the packages, no matter how integral they are to R, is still a part you don't ask about ON STACK....

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre in R Studio Server GUI. There is 'rstudio-server' tag.

Comment: @Patrice I don't want to offend anyone. If I did, I apologize. Can I ask questions about core an base R packages?

Comment: Eugene you come here for help and reject all advice people are giving you. Then you start saying that people on stackoverflow don't know R. There are a lot of R experts here, and the tag is very popular. All this, instead of improving your question so it can be understood. Rene answer proves by the absurd that it's very difficult to understand & confusing. Remove the useless parts, focus on your problem, show what works but what you need and is missing.

Comment: I added the code and removed the ambiguities. But I see my question on hold by reason I don't understand.

Comment: @EugeneVlasov - Give it more then 38 minutes.  Stack Overflow is not a resource where you can get help instantly.

Comment: @SecurityHound sure, no problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I still don't have an answer. So I can get that I was downvoted by people who does not understand R language. It is bad for such a good knowledge database as Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Patrice I am still waiting an answer for simple question - are packages `core` and `base` not a part of R language and what part of R does not consist of packages? It is a very simple question for such an expert as you are.

Comment: @EugeneVlasov you don't have an answer because your question has been put on hold, and noone is voting to reopen it despite the "meta effect" (which gets you a lot more downvotes that the question deserves), because it's off-topic.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You mean _Stack Overflow hate effect_, eh? :)
No worries, I've got the answer from RStudio themselves. If you kindly open answers I will put the answer there. Thank you for the lesson - _don't ask, don't tell_.

Comment: If you improve your question (which is still unclear) I'll reopen

Answer (score 16):

> I am trying to implement multiple file user choice in a script in RStudio Server running on a server with no window manager.

Okay, so you're down to only using the console then?

> X11 on Ubuntu 18 to be precise.

Or not, as X11 is the X Window thingy

> RChoiceDialog and tcltk packages don't work without GUI.

But wait, don't we have X available then?

> Preferably I would use filters too - only text files.

Oh, hold on, there is another requirement.

Here is my advice.

Show the code/script/config you tried are experimented with to get that multiple file user choice thingy going. Include the script, the steps you took, maybe a screenshot to support your story. Do you have a single file user choice working? Add that example because maybe you're missing a single option/setting to make that fly.

Alternatively do use the packages that require a GUI and that have the functionality you need. From there you can ask how you can keep that working without the window-manager and/or X.

Both of these approaches will help those that know the answer at which foundation they can build. For your question as is, it is hard to judge. And therefore the question is broad, if not unclear which is a close reason at best.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that it is clear that X11 is **missing**. The all code is here: `file.choose()` and it works fine. `jchoose.files(
  default = getwd(),
  caption = "Select blank files",
  multi = TRUE,
  filters = getDefaultFilters()[8, ],
  index = nrow(filters)` - does not work. No surprise, it needs window manager as said in the title.

Comment: _Oh, hold on, there is another requirement_
Usually a function for choosing files has filters inside.

Comment: @EugeneVlasov I know. The point is that a question should stick to one topic and one topic only, specially if you have nothing working yet. Small steps works best here, for you and for future visitors. They are the ones we want to serve.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. But I can't imagine a smaller question than "how to choose multiple files". I can live without filters as I mentioned in my question. Anyway, thanks.